# ¿Como quito el margen de la parte de arriba?

Tags: html, css

Tengo este código de HTML y este de CSS:

```css
 .burua{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#000000;
  height:65px;
 }
 
 #p1{
  font-size: 350%;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 a:link{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000000;
  
 }
 a:visited{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration:none;
 }

 #nombreEndi{
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  color: #8B0000; 
  font-family: "TituloEndi";
  font-size:40px;
 }

 .header{
  height:100px; width:100%;
  text-align:center;
 }

 .menu{
  height: 40px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align:center;  
  background-color: #191919;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #191919, #000000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #191919, #000000);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #191919), color-stop(1, #000000));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#191919, #000000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #191919, #000000);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#191919', endColorStr='#000000');
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
 }
 .wrapper{ height:2000px; 
    width:100%; 
    padding-top:20px
 }
 .menu-fixed {
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1000;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
 }
 ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block; 
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100%;
 }

 body{
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("../ARGAZKIAK/background.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;

 }

 #menu li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
 }

 .listaArriba{
  color:  #000000;
  width: 150px;
 }

 #titulua{
   background-color:#000;
   text-align:center;
   margin-left: 300px;
   margin-top: 7px;
 }

 #signUp{
  height:250px;
  position:fixed;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
 }
 #logIn{
  height:250px;
  position:fixed;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 575px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
 }
 #help{
  height:250px;
  position:fixed;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 900px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
 }
 .argazkia{
  margin-left:10px;
 }
 #azalpena{
  font-size: 35px;
 }
 

 
 #behealdea{
  margin-top:0px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #191919;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #191919, #000000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #191919, #000000);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #191919), color-stop(1, #000000));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#191919, #000000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #191919, #000000);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#191919', endColorStr='#000000');
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<header class="burua">
    <div class = "cabecera">
   <p id="p1">DiruBank</p>
    </div>
</header>
  <div class="menu" id="menu">
   <nav class="top-menu">
    <ul class = "navigation">
     <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="#">GIGS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="#">MUSIC</a> </li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="#">LYRICS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 <div id="signUp">
  <img class="argazkia" id="arg1" src="../ARGAZKIAK/signUp.png"/>
  <p id="azalpena">Sign up</p>
 </div>
 
 <div id="logIn">
  <img class="argazkia" id="arg2" src="../ARGAZKIAK/login.png"/>
  <p id="azalpena">Log In</p>
 </div>
 <div id="help">
  <img class="argazkia" id="arg3" src="../ARGAZKIAK/help.png"/>
  <p id="azalpena">Help</p>
 </div> 
 
  <footer id="behealdea">
   <a href="#"> Egileak </a>
  </footer>
```

Y la web se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no entiendo es que genera el cacho gris de la parte de arriba. 
 Saludos.

Comment: #p1{margin-top:0}

Comment: Gracias, ponlo como repsuesta y te la marco como tal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en no setear **margin** a `#p1` (que tiene un font-size:350%).
Ponle un `margin-top:0` y sacará el espacio de arriba.

Saludos!